# How I can create with multiple types of users, using a simple login with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid, Devise and Rails 3.1.

I have four models: Students, Teacher, Parents and School (the main account). All them will log in on system. But, I don't want create four ways to login. I want create an unique login method using anyone this models, but with respectives roles (This is the minor problem, I already can do that with CanCan).

Anybody have a easy solution, without create a programming-hell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, people logging on to your system are all `Users`. So either you choose to let the classes`Teacher, Student, Parent, SchoolRepresentative` to inherit from `User` using STI.

Most of the times I prefer simply that a `User` has `roles`. And the role would then be `teacher, student ...` 
The `roles` define what a user is allowed to see.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it would be really great to include examples of implementations here